# Losing Current Filter on PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Can somebody please help me and tell me where I am going wrong. I have a dashboard that shows a list of errors. There is a textbox at the top with `type="date"` allowing the user to select a date. The list then updates itself to show the errors that happened on the date that has been selected. I am wanting to implement PagedList on this but when I click on the second page it doesn't show any results whatsoever

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                           where s.TimeUtc == DateTime.Today
                           select s;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            default:
                applications = applications.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeUtc);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";


        DateTime userSelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(Request["datePicker"]).Date;

        string dateString = userSelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        if (dateString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
           dateString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = dateString;

        var startDate = userSelectedDate.Date;
        var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);

        var applications = from s in db.ElmahErrors
                           //where s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate
                           select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateString))
        {
            applications = applications.Where(s => s.TimeUtc >= startDate && s.TimeUtc < endDate);
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            default:
                applications = applications.OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeUtc);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = Int32.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultPageSize"]);
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(applications.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

#### View

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DataIntelligence.Models.ElmahError>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Errors By Day";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Errors By Day</h2>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Day", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmSearch" }))
{
    <label for="datePicker">Find By Date:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("datePicker", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @type = "date"})

}

<script>
    $("#datePicker").change(function () {
        $("#frmSearch").submit();
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Application
        </th>
        <th>
            Host
        </th>
        <th>
            Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Message
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td style="width:400px;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id=item.ErrorId})"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application) </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Host)
            </td>
            <td style="width:550px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeUtc)
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    string parameterValue = item.Message.Substring(0, 8);
                }

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => parameterValue)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

I have tried changing from `POST` to `GET` but I can't seem to get my head around how to get it working.

Could someone please advise me on what to change in order to get my PagedList working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PagedList, as [most of paging modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139443/is-there-an-mvc-pager-that-uses-post-instead-of-get) you may find, uses GET, not POST, when you click on the next page. So the request arrives not to the action marked with `HttpPost`, but to the default one. Therefore date filter is not applied, and you receive second page with today's errors. I am guessing there were not enough errors today (good, huh?) to fill second page with data.

I would recommend you to switch to a single action that handles GET requests only. After all, this is the recommended way for idempotent operations like data viewing. POST should be used, ideally, only when data is being changed on server.

Comment: tried this but then it stops the `Request["datePicker"]` working which gives me the error `String reference not set to an instanceof String`

Comment: @D.M, note that you need your form to use FormMethod.Get as well. And datePicker should really be an input parameter of the action method

Comment: yep changed that too, i'm fairly new to this so sorry if this should be easy