# Mvc4 paging and filter using strongly typed Viemodel Conto University tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, filtering, paging

I am following Conto University tutorial concerning the paging and filtering implementation. I want to filter my results (IEnumerable) by passing multiple values and not just a string(for example idnumber,statusid...). I want to validate my filtering input values( idnumber,statusid..) So I decided to use a strongly typed viewModel and an Ajax Beginform as I want that to be done asynchronous.The problem I have is while in the Conto University tutorial the filter is just a string and can be passed through viewbag, I canot find a way to pass a viewmodel bag to the controoller.I can pass the viewmodel from controller to view and I can even implenet the filtering but whenever I click on change page the previously applied filter is removed. So back to the tutorial the use the viewbag to pass the previous applied filter from view back to the controller. Is there a way to pass a viewmodel(as I said i got a viewmodel as filter) back to the conrooler?  My classes look like this

```
public class Student
{ 
public int ID
public int stasusid
public int idnumber
public string Lastname
public string Firstanme
public int Grade
public virtual School
}
```

The viewModel I use is almost the same with my student class but also contains an enumerator to check if is empty and  does not contain any virtual memebers-navigation

```
   public class FilterPerson
    {
    public int stasusid
    public int idnumber
    public string Lastname
    public string Firstanme
    public int Grade
    public int SchoolID

public bool Empty
{
  get
 {
            return (!stasusid.HasValue &&
                  !idnumber.HasValue&&
                   !Grade.HasValue &&
                   !SchoolID.HasValue &&
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Lastname) &&
                    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Firstanme));           
            }
    }
}
```

My controller is almost the same with the tutorial with the difference that I use a model instead of searchstring to filter the results

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, ViewModels.FilterPerson filter, int? page)
{
ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

ViewBag.GradeSortParm = sortOrder == "grade_asc" ? "grade_desc" : "grade_asc";

ViewBag.StatusSortParm=ortOrder == "status_asc" ? "status_desc" : "status_asc";

ViewBag.IdNumberSortParm=ortOrder == "idnumber_asc" ? "idnumber_desc" : "idnumber_asc";
   ViewBag.SchoolSortParm = sortOrder == "school_asc" ? "school_desc" : "school_asc";       
var students = from s in db.Students select s;
if (!filter.Empty )
 {
Cards = db.Students.Where(
s => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.FirstName) || s.Firstname.Contains(filter.FirstName))&& 
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.LastName) || s.Lastname.Contains(filter.LastName)) && 
(!filter.stasusid.HasValue || s.Status.stasusid== filter.stasusid) && (!filter.grade.HasValue || s.grade== filter.grade) && 
    (!filter.idnumber.HasValue || s.idnumber== filter.idnumber)
 (!filter.SchoolID.HasValue || s.School.ID== filter.SchoolID)
    }



ViewBag.CurrentFilter = filter;


switch (sortOrder)
{
case "name_desc":
students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
     break;
case "grade_asc":
       students = students.OrderBy(s => s.grade);
      break;
case "grade_desc":
       students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.grade);
       break;
case "status_asc":
       students = students.OrderBy(s => s.stasusid);
       break;
case "status_desc":
       students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.stasusid);
       break;
case "idnumber_asc":
       students = students.OrderBy(s => s.idnumber);
       break;
case "idnumber_desc":
       students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.idnumber);
       break;
default:  // Name ascending 
        students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
       break;
}

int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

and finally my view looks like this

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Grade", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GradeSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
          <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("School id", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SchoolSortParm , currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>

         <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IdNumberSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>

         <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StatusSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
            </td>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SchoolID)
            </td>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idnumber)
            </td>

             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stasusid)
            </td>


            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

and I implement my filter using a partial view and an ajax begin form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Student", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Results", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{


    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(idnumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idnumber)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idnumber)
        </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)

        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Grade)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Grade)
        </div>


         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SchoolID)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchoolID)
        </div>

             <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.statusid)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.statusid)
        </div>
<input type="submit" class="SearchCards" value="Search" />  
}
```

So the basic problem I face is that when i click on change page I can't pass the already applied filter back to the controller as it is not a string anymore but a viewmodel class filter. Any help would be really appreaciated

Comment: I need to propably do a post from the mvcpager: I found this solution but does not look very pretty to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139443/is-there-an-mvc-pager-that-uses-post-instead-of-get